# What is the real meaning of energy released in nuclear fission?

Tags: energy-conservation, nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

In a nuclear fission reaction the total energy and thus the mass of the products are lower than the total energy of the reactants. I understand the the difference in this energy can be used in a nuclear reactor/atomic bomb. But in the physical sense how does this energy manifest, is the kinetic energy of the reactants or some EM wave emission or combination of both. Also if it is the kinetic energy of reactants, wouldn't that energy be already included in the total energy of reactants?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In what form is the binding energy released after nuclear fission?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/763986/)

Comment: Total energy including energy of radiation is not lower, that would violate conservation of energy. The only way you will get lower energy of products is if you do not count some contributions to energy, such as the released neutron radiation, or EM radiation (which includes gamma radiation and UV/visible/IR radiation).